# Can not set Momentum of optimizer

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, momentum, sgd

I am using the SGD optimizer and want to set the momentum after initialization similar to learning rate scheduling by using `tf.keras.backend.set_value(optimizer.momentum, momentumValue)`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/set_value

However, all I get is following error:

```
AttributeError: 'LossScaleOptimizer' object has no attribute 'momentum'
```

Is there any way to set the momentum?
This is important for implementing the 1Cycle Policy as the momentum should also cycle, but I can´t believe there is no way to adjust the momentum in keras after initialization.

Comment: Facing the same problem for the same task. Did you manage to solve it?